# jQuery UI Droppable - clone the droppable element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-droppable

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dy556efs/2/

The elements on the left side should be cloned when dropped over to the right side. Currently, they are completely moved over - and can't get the clone helper to work properly.

Could you point me in the right direction?

```
$(".social-msl-link-label").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".social-msl-group-list",
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone"
});

$(".social-msl-links-order li").droppable({
    accept : ".social-msl-link-label",
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    greedy : true,
    hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        $(ui.draggable).detach().css({position : 'relative', top: 'auto',left: 'auto'}).appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the documentation for the [`helper` property](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) it seems like the element is only cloned *while* dragging it. In other words, you still have to manually clone the element before detaching/appending it. Use the [`.clone()` method](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) before detaching it:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/z6pb0v10/)

```
$(".social-msl-links-order li").droppable({
  accept: ".social-msl-link-label",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  greedy: true,
  hoverClass: 'highlight',
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    $(ui.draggable).clone(true).detach().css({
      position: 'relative',
      top: 'auto',
      left: 'auto'
    }).appendTo(this);
  }
});
```

---

If you want to remove duplicates, you could iterate over the droppable elements and compare the text of the previously dropped element with the siblings. Inside of the `drop` callback:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7b8bqzsh/)

```
// ...
$(this).siblings().filter(function () {
  return $(this).text().trim() === $(ui.draggable).text().trim();
}).empty();
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Works great, would you know how to extend this further so that the right column will only accept 1 of each item. So in the JSFiddle example, if you added "Facebook" more than once, it would remove the previous version?

Comment: amazing work, thank you for your help! Actually makes sense now that you've written it out, couldn't figure out a way to compare other elements before.

Comment: @JoshCrozier why `detach()`..?

Comment: @TJ - That's the code the OP was originally using. You can read the difference between `remove()` and `detach()` in the documentation.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I though it was added by you for some purpose, nvm. since `clone()` method returns an in memory element, I was wondering what's the use of calling `detach()` on it... I didn't see OP's fiddle. Looking at it again, just noticed that `ui.draggable` is a jquery object no need to do `$(ui.draggable)`...